# allow paste (ctrl+v) in output windows (interactive)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm here again for an hint.
Does anyone know if there is some way to allow paste in an output window interactive interface?
Here a sample code:

```
%window mywind
#2 @5 "Just a try"
#3 @5 "why here CTRL+V is not working??"
#4 @5 variable 10 attr=underline;

data _null_;
%display mywind;
%let varval=&variable.;
run;
```

many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here I suspect is that Windows is handling the ctrl+V, and SAS's windowing system here isn't really made to work with that in quite the right way.

However, you can use the KEYS dialog (type KEYS into the command bar, or F9 by default) to assign many key combinations.  I just typed `paste` into the Ctrl+Y line for example, hit enter, then ran your code and it pasted correctly.

Comment: This worked, as always Joe, you're maybe the best contributor here for sas base. Many thanks for your efforts.